# Who was the first to discover that the curvature of an embedded surface is the product of the principal curvatures?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview

The invention of intrinsic differential geometry is usually attributed to Gauss in the context of his *theorema egregium* but the notion of the curvature of an embedded surface existed before. Who was the first to discover that the curvature of an embedded surface is the product of the principal curvatures?

In http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4736 the author states: "In 1763, Euler started
a thorough study of curvature of embedded surfaces. In 1767, he found an
expression of the curvature in terms of the product of principal curvatures."

This seems to suggest that the curvature Euler is talking about is what is known today as Gaussian curvature, the latter being the product of principal curvatures.  However, this comment in 1409.4736 seems to be based on a different comment in the 2008 encyclopedia of scientific biography at http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Johann_Tobias_Mayer.aspx#1-1G2:2830901353-full which states:

"In 1763 Euler made the first substantial advance in the study of the curvature of surfaces; in particular, he expressed the curvature of an arbitrary normal section by principal curvatures (1767)."

This of course does not imply any relation to Gaussian curvature and on the contrary suggests that Euler only dealt with curvatures of curves obtained as cross-sections of the embedded surface.  However, it is possible that 1409.4736 has a different source for this claim.

The relevant paper by Euler is apparently http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E333.pdf where on page 143 Euler discusses the two radii of curvature.

Comment: Isn't it called the Gaussian curvature because Gauss discovered it?

Comment: Apparently not. It goes back at least to Euler; perhaps earlier. Seems like the typical situation as far as attributions go :-)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I believe Gauss' contribution is his theorema egregium, i.e., the Gaussian curvature is intrinsic.

Comment: There is a special SE site on History of Math and Science. I think this question has a higher chance there.

Comment: Why would Gauss curvature have any more significance than the principal curvatures or the mean curvature, if it were not known to be intrinsic?

Comment: @DeaneYang, good question. I will add some clarifications to my question.

Comment: There is  Whitehead's Law stating that ``everything of importance has been said before by someone who did not discover it."  https://michaelberryphysics.wordpress.com/quotations/

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu, well, Euler did give a rigorous treatment of the fact that there are two orthogonal principal directions and that the curvature of the normal section is the well-known expression in terms of the principal curvatures. I don't have the impression the principle you cited sheds much light on either Euler or Gauss.

Comment: @katz  Take this principle  with a grain of salt. Arnold used to say that  ``Discoveries are rarely attributed to the correct person", himself included.

Comment: I still don't know what the original definition of curvature was (before it was known that it was just the product of the principal curvatures).

Comment: @DeaneYang, as far as I know it was Gauss who first defined the invariant as the product and until I read the paper 1409.4736 I though nobody considered the product as a meaningful invariant before Gauss, but the paper seems to imply otherwise.  It could be that the paper misinterpreted the encyclopedia article as I suggested. I guess I should change the title of this question to "did anybody consider the product of principal curvatures before Gauss"?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu True, but in this case Gaussian curvature seems to be correctly attributed to Gauss, contrary to what I read in 1409.4736.

Comment: crossposted to http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/did-anybody-consider-the-product-of-the-principal-curvatures-before-gauss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start with your first quotation:

"In 1763, Euler started a thorough study of curvature of embedded surfaces. In 1767, he found an expression of the curvature in terms of the product of principal curvatures."

Karin Reich's article in *Leonhard Euler: Life, Work and Legacy* (p. 482 in particular) explains what this is supposed to mean. As you know,
Euler attacked the curvature of surfaces at some point P in terms of the curvatures of curves cut out by planes normal to the tangent plane at P. He found that the planes for which the maximal and minimal curvature occurs 
are orthogonal to each other, and then he developed a formula for the curvature of the curve cut out by any plane normal to the tangent plane in terms of the
maximal and minimal curvature and the angle $\phi$ between the plane and the principal section. So "the curvature" here is definitely not Gauss's curvature.

The remark about the years 1763 and 1767 is even "curiouser": Euler presented his article E333 in 1763 to the Berlin Academy and it was published in 1767. So we are dealing with one and the same paper here.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know who originally defined Gauss curvature, but here is a long comment about the curvature of a surface. The second fundamental form of a surface is usually defined in terms of the Gauss map. It seems unlikely to me that curvature was originally defined in terms of the Gauss map, and I think Gauss introduced it because it is much easier to do computations using it.

Here is what I consider a more natural and maybe the original way to define the second fundamental form:

Given a point on a smooth surface, you can always move the surface so that the point is at the origin and the tangent plane is the $xy$-plane. The surface is therefore locally the graph of a function $f$ over the $xy$-plane.

The function $f$ is uniquely defined up to sign and a rotation of the $xy$-plane. Therefore, any function of $f$ and its derivatives, evaluated at $0$, that is invariant under sign and rotations defines a pointwise geometric invariant of the surface.

Since $f(0) = \partial_xf(0) = \partial_yf(0) = 0$, the simplest possible geometric invariant, up to a rotation of the $xy$-plane, is the Hessian, $\partial^2f(0)$. This defines the second fundamental form. The eigenvalues of $\partial^2f(0)$ are rotationally invariant and therefore define geometric invariants of $S$ up to sign. This defines the principal curvatures. Any even function of the eigenvalues defines a local geometric invariant, period . In particular, the determinant of $\partial^2f(0)$ is such an invariant and clearly a fundamental one. This defines Gauss curvature.

This provides an easy way to define local extrinsic geometric invariants of a surface. What is not at all obvious is how to identify which are intrinsic. If you try to do any computations using definition above, you get a horrible mess. I speculate that the real contributions of Gauss are introducing the Gauss map, to simplify calculations involving the second fundamental form and identifying Gauss curvature as an intrinsic invariant.

ADDED: The definition above of the second fundamental form can be used to give a straightforward proof for the Theorema Egregium of Gauss. I wrote a short note here: http://www.deaneyang.com/papers/gauss.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Why in the world is this "community wiki" all of a sudden? This is a specific question with arguably a unique answer, determined chronologically.

Comment: Deane, this is exactly how I teach differential geometry in my undergraduate class. See http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/egreglongb.pdf I don't think it is impossible that other mathematicians may have considered the product before Gauss, because as you point out this is a natural invariant to consider, but I don't have any evidence either way.

Comment: I believe only my answer is community wiki. I did that, because it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @DeaneYang I would guess this is just an afterthought of how the concept really evolved, as I perceived some Erlangen flavor that only appeared after Klein.

Comment: @DeaneYang, nice proof.  I think mine is even shorter though; see pages 90-91 of the notes linked above.  Perhaps we can start a separate thread on the shortest proof of theorema egregium...

Comment: katz, your proof is beautiful and much shorter than mine. The only point to mine is that you can start from the beginning (definition of a surface as being locally a graph and the formula for the length of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$) to the end using only basic multivariable differential calculus, without the explicit use of the Riemannian metric and its connection or even the Gauss map (even though they are used implicitly). It isolates the two difficult steps in the proof, namely the two tensor calculations (which rely on the fundamental and extremely important fact that partials commute.)

Comment: @DeaneYang, thanks.  Note that my proof does not use Riemannian metrics, nor connections, nor the Gauss map, nor yet any tensors, but merely a calculation with indices conveniently arranged.